# How to partial complete text input

Tags: jquery, validation, html, autocomplete

I know the title doesn't capture what I'm trying to ask but here is what I'm trying to do:

// desired format is: 123-123-1234

When the user enters 123 (the first three characters) how can I append the hyphen -
Then when the user enters 123 (the second three characters) how can I append the hyphen - again 
And then allow the user only to enter the last four numbers?

I have a function that validates the US Phone number format I want:

```
/* US Phone # */
'us_phonenumber':function($fld) {
    var v = $fld.val();

    if(v.length == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return /^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/.test(v);
},
```

Just curious if I could add some sort of partial auto complete method while still validating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" />
<br /><a href="#" id="check">Click me!</a>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#check").click(function(){
    var pNum = $("input").val();
    var vNum = pNum.slice(0, 3)+"-"+pNum.slice(3, 6)+"-"+pNum.slice(6, 10);
    $("input").val(vNum);
    return false;
});
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ueyhE/**

Type in your number, then press "Click me!".

**EDIT:**

Using [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change):

```
$("input").click(function(){
    var pNum = $(this).val();
    var vNum = pNum.slice(0, 3)+"-"+pNum.slice(3, 6)+"-"+pNum.slice(6, 10);
    $(this).val(vNum);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know about doing during input, but after the input is complete might be less confusing for the user, or less margin for error.

```
var string = '1234567890';
var formattedString = '';
var index;
for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    index = string.charAt(i);   
    (i == 3 || i == 6) ? formattedString = formattedString + '-' + index : formattedString = formattedString + index;
}
alert(formattedString);
```